# remove data between two word with sed

Tags: bash, sed

Assume we have a file with this content:

```
<tag1>
junk1
junk2
</tag1>
data1
data2
data3
<tag1>junk3</tag1>
data4
data5
```

So, we wanna remove all data between two strings what are `<tag1>` and `</tag1>` here. I can do the job with `sed` command like:

```
cat input | sed '/<tag1>/,/<\/tag1>/d'
```

but there is a problem, the command doesn't work properly, and data after the one-liner `tag1` tag is removed from the output. The output of the above command :

```
data1
data2
data3
```

So, the main question is, how can we remove data between two strings/tags/patterns even if those are one-line or multi-line data?

thanks

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @HatLess data1-5

Comment: is the input real and valid XML? if so you should explore `xpath` solutions

Comment: Unfortunately no, @Fravadona, the file consists of different data type such as json, html, xml, js, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this. I've been struggling with this exact problem for a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As `sed` cannot parse xml files, there are many cases that `sed` does
  not work well (e.g. tags within a comment tag).
- As `sed` regex does not support the non-greedy match, we need to
  consider about workarounds.

Based on the above, would you please try:

```
sed $'s/<tag1>/&\\\n/g' input | sed '/<tag1>/,/<\/tag1>/d'
```

Output:

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
```

The first `sed` just puts a line break after the `<tag1>`.
Although it works for the provided example, please note there are
many cases it doesn't work well (e.g. `</tag1>` is missing).

Comment: thanks @tshiono , that works like a charm! one more question, in your solution we can't use `/*` and `*/` instead of `<tag1>` and `</tag1>`, I use it in this way : `sed $'s/\/\*/&\\\n/g' input | sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d'` and got this error : `sed: 1: "s//*/&\ , /g": bad flag in substitute command: '&' `

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but your modified code works well on my environment. Tested with GNU sed 3.02, 4.0, and 4.7. All versions work.

Comment: As an alternative, please try a `perl` version: `perl -0777 -pe 's#/\*[\s\S]*?\*/\s*##g' input`.

Comment: Thank you so much for his answer. I've been struggling with this exact problem for a while, and your solution is simple and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Note: `cat input | sed SCRIPT` is useless, simply `sed SCRIPT input`. Let's assume that:

- you use GNU sed,
- you may have other tags (e.g., `<tag2>`),
- you may have several groups on the same line ( `a<tag1>b</tag1>c<tag1>d</tag1>e`),
- you don't have nested groups (`<tag1>a<tag1>b</tag1>c</tag1>`),
- all your `<tag1>` and `</tag1>` are properly balanced.

GNU sed has the neat `-z` option that considers the NUL character as the line terminator, instead of the newline character. So, as your input file does not contain any NUL character, this allows to consider its content as one single string (with newline characters in it).

We can thus start deleting the `<tag1>...</tag1>` groups without considering whether they are on the same "line" or not. But as sed is greedy we cannot simply `s#<tag1>.*</tag1>##g` as it would remove everything between the first `<tag1>` and the last `</tag1>`: if you have more than one group it would also remove the text between groups.

We can however loop over two substitute commands: one that removes the empty groups `<tag1></tag1>`, followed by one that removes any single character after `<tag1>`, and repeat as long as single characters are removed:

```sh
$ cat input
<tag1>
junk1
junk2
</tag1>
data1
data2<tag1>junk3</tag1>data3<tag1>junk4</tag1>data4
data5
<tag1>junk5</tag1>
data6
<tag1>junk6</tag1>
$ sed -Ez ':a;s#<tag1></tag1>##g;s#(<tag1>).#\1#g;ta' input

data1
data2data3data4
data5

data6
```

Explanation: `:a` is a label, used for looping. `s#<tag1></tag1>##g` removes all empty groups. `s#(<tag1>).#\1#g` removes any single character after `<tag1>`. `ta` branches to label `a` if the previous substitution was successful. In other words we loop until there are no
substitutions; in each iteration we remove all empty groups and remove one character between all non-empty `<tag1>`, `</tag1>` pairs. When we stop, all groups have been deleted.

If the empty lines it leaves shall also be removed we just add one final command that deletes all empty "lines". It does that by replacing any string of spaces (can be empty) between two newline characters (or between the beginning of the pattern space and a newline character), by a single newline character (or nothing if it was at the beginning of the pattern space):

```sh
$ sed -Ez ':a;s#<tag1></tag1>##g;s#(<tag1>).#\1#g;ta;s#(\`|\n)\s*\n#\1#g' input
data1
data2data3data4
data5
data6
```